# css - change aspect ratio of an image without wrapper

Tags: css, image

I have the width and height of image A,
and I want to change the aspect ratio of image B to have the aspect ratio of A without any container element, such as `div`, `a`, etc.

Then, How does image B have the aspect ratio of A without any container element?

Comment: Did you try `height: auto` on CSS?

Comment: @AnhTuan I've tried that, but it didn't work. Can you post the css?

Comment: I posted my answer, you can look into that.

Comment: Show your code, please.

Comment: @cale_b I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the aspect ratio without a container, you can use a transform on image B. This will of course distort the image, but that's kinda unavoidable since you are changing the aspect ratio.

A `scale` transform will shrink or expand an element by a multiple you specify.

In order for this to work, you need to know how image B's size relates to image A's. This won't be totally automatic.

In the example below, we have two images: A. is 200x300, and B. is 400x100.

We want B to become the same size as A, so we need to cut B's width in half and multiply its height by 3. In CSS, that means we do `scaleX(0.5)` and `scaleY(3.0)`.

The end result is this:

```css
img:nth-child(2) {
  transform: scaleX(0.5) scaleY(3.0);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x300">

<img src="http://placehold.it/400x100">
```

You can also pick different numbers to get the same aspect ratio but not have the two images be exactly the same size. For example, `transform: scaleX(0.25) scaleY(1.5)` would give you image B at image A's aspect ratio, but half the size of image A.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `height: auto` CSS attribute. Even when the HTML attributes `width` and `height` are not keeping aspect ratio, `height: auto` CSS will fix this.

```
.minisize {
  height: auto!important
}
```

Demo of my code. Even when width is 300px and height is 1px, it still show an smaller image that keeping aspect ration: https://jsfiddle.net/99qrn65L/

Comment: Thanks, but in my case, the `src` of low size image is not the same as origin`s.

Comment: It not depend on source image. It can work when your `<img>` have `width` attribute or even don't have I think.

Comment: *height: auto CSS will fix this.* **NO.** how can css know the ratio of origin image? This method is only possible when the `src` is the same as origin's.